# Controlling the tracker when using twinx

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

The tracker in the lower-right corner (highlighted in red) reports y-values relative to the y-axis on the right.

How can I get the tracker to report y-values relative to the y-axis on the left instead?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(6)
numdata = 100
t = np.linspace(0.05, 0.11, numdata)
y1 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(numdata) - 0.5) * 40000
y2 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(numdata) - 0.5) * 0.002

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(t, y1, 'r-', label='y1')
ax2.plot(t, y2, 'g-', label='y2')

ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

I know swapping `y1` with `y2` will make the tracker report y1-values,
but this also places the `y1` tickmarks on the right-hand side, which is not what I want to happen.

```
ax1.plot(t, y2, 'g-', label='y2')
ax2.plot(t, y1, 'r-', label='y1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, found it: `ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")`.
Instead of trying to "control the tracker", you can swap the location of the y-axes.

```
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")

ax1.plot(t, y2, 'g-', label='y1')
ax2.plot(t, y1, 'r-', label='y2')
```

AFAIK, the tracker always follows `ax2` when using `twinx`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please note that if you create an `ax3= ax1.twiny()` axes after ax1 and ax2, the tracker goes to ax3 and you have again it reporting y1 values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(6)
numdata = 100
t = np.linspace(0.05, 0.11, numdata)
y1 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(numdata) - 0.5) * 40000
y2 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(numdata) - 0.5) * 0.002

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(t, y1, 'r-', label='y1')
ax2.plot(t, y2, 'g-', label='y2')

ax1.legend()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
ax3.set_xticks([])
plt.show()
```