# How to tell interaction window which y value to display with twin axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I'm working on a Python script to display the results of musical pitch analysis. I have twinned the first axis and supplied a custom ticker so I can view the results in both Hz and Pitch. The relevant code, based on the example at https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/gallery/api/two_scales.html is:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.set_ylabel('f0/Hz')

# read and process data, draw green rectangle on ax1... then

ax1.plot(t, f0)

# Make a second y axis with note names on it.
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('Pitch')
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(PitchTicker(19,numticks=30))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda f, pos: 
hz_to_tuning19(f)[0]))

# All other code refers to ax1, then...

plt.title('[{}:{}] {}'.format(first,last,title))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This working as desired except in one respect, which is unfortunately a major issue for the end user. When the window is displayed and the pointer is moved over the axes, the Y value shown is that from the twinned axis, `ax2`, not from the first one.

Interaction window with twinned axes:
[image]

The Y value given in the bottom right hand corner is the value given by `ax2`'s `ticker.FuncFormatter`, and I can't find a way to make it display `ax1`'s value instead so that the value of `f0` in Hz gets displayed.

I have found that one possible solution is to draw the line and triangle on `ax1`, then create `ax2` and say

```
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
ax1.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
```

but this seems rather counter-intuitive and feels like it might break in future.

I have tried calling `plt.sca(ax1)` and even `ax2.set_axisbelow(True)` before `plt.show()` but this doesn't change anything.

Is there an official way to tell the interaction window which X and Y values to display when reporting mouse position?

Comment: Take a look at this SO post see if it helps you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/21585524/6361531

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston ─ indeed it does help (a lot!). Quite a big chunk of code to get done what I wanted, but very flexible and comprehensive. It'll come in useful again.